# Inner join query is showng 0 results

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am facing strange issue with OpenCart (v: 3.0.3.7) query. I am trying to pull product and product_descrition table data using `Inner Join` but getting 0 result. This query is working fine if I am using `Left Join` instead of `Inner Join`. Also query is showing result for product_id but null values in pd.name.

Note: Same query is working find when I am running it directly in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT p.product_id, pd.name
FROM oc_product p
Inner JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) AND ( pd.name LIKE "%test%") AND p.manufacturer_id = "14"
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY p.product_id ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need `INNER JOUN`? use `LEFT JOIN`...
You can try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) AND pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.product_id ASC
```

Comment: with left join i am getting all the records from the products table even though product's name not existing in product_description table. 
As i have already mentioned that Left join is working fine. I am sure this issue is related to opencart since same query is working fine with phpmyadmin